# Obtaining database joined table with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Ive been trying to join two tables but only showing a limited amount (2) of results from the joined table. Unfortunately I havent been able to obtain the correct results. These are my tables:

**Destinations**

```
id   name
------------
1    Bahamas
2    Caribbean
3    Barbados
```

**Sailings**

```
id  name            destination
---------------------------------
1   Adventure       1  
2   For Kids        2
3   All Inclusive   3
4   Seniors         1
5   Singles         2
6   Disney          1
7   Adults          2
```

This is the query Ive tried:

```
SELECT 
   d.name as Destination,
   s.name as Sailing 
FROM destinations d
JOIN sailings s 
  ON s.destination = d.id
LIMIT 2
```

But this gives me 2 due to the limit:

```
Destination    Sailing
-------------------------
Bahamas        Adventure
Caribbean      For Kids
```

**SAMPLE:** [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/159843/1)

I would like `LIMIT 2` to be applied only to the joined table `sailings`

Expected Results:

```
Destination    Sailing
-------------------------
Bahamas        Adventure
Bahamas        Seniors
Caribbean      Singles
Caribbean      For Kids
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please post some fiddle or sql schema

Comment: @sumit [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/159843/3) is posted now

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select tmp.name as destination,d.name as sailings  from (
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    destination
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        name,
        destination,
        @rn := IF(@p = destination, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
        @p := destination
    FROM sailings
    JOIN (SELECT @p := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
    ORDER BY destination 
) AS T1
WHERE rn <= 2
  )tmp
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM destinations limit 0,2) d 
  ON(tmp.destination=d.id)
```

I have made 2 derived table and joined them

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not show me what I need (unless im not running the fiddle correctly). The results i get is 3 rather than 2 .. Can you post a link to the fiddle you created?

Comment: I understand your problem, thinking  about it :)

Comment: yea its been kicking my butt. Take your time, thanks.

Comment: This is my effort ,:)

Comment: That is a lot of query

Comment: yea, your query is faster, I checked :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you want to take the two highest (or lowest) members of a group, for each group in the table.  In this case, you want the first two sailings for each destination group.

The canonical way you would handle this query in a database which supported analytic functions would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  But since MySQL does not support this, we can simulate it using session variables:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @destination = NULL;

SELECT
    t.Destination,
    t.Sailing
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @row_number:=CASE WHEN @destination = Destination
                          THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @destination:=Destination AS Destination,
        Sailing,
        id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT s.id AS id, d.name AS Destination, s.name AS Sailing
        FROM destinations d
        INNER JOIN sailings s
            ON s.destination = d.id
    ) t
    ORDER BY
        Destination,
        id
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
ORDER BY
    t.Destination,
    t.rn;
```

Note that Barbados appears as single row, because in your sample data it only has one sailing.  If you also want to restrict to only destinations having two or more sailings, this can also be done.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: plus 1 ,I was almost there , you beat me superb :)

Comment: @sumit I noticed some very strange behavior with the session variables.  To get it to work, I needed to wrap the join query as a subquery and then work with that.  If you have an explanation for this, then post and I can also upvote you.

Comment: This seems to work according to the Rextester.. However it is very overwhelming.. im wondering if theres a simpler way of doing this.. I will inspect it more in depth and dissect it to understand it better, thanks.

Comment: @CodeGodie If you have a strong need for queries like this, then you might want to consider switching to an enterprise database such as MySQL's evil twin sister, Oracle (or SQL Server, Postgres, etc.).  They have functions which make queries like this one very easy.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I have added my answer, but its almost same like yours. I didn't face any session variable strange behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
SELECT 
   d.name as Destination,
   s.name as Sailing 
FROM sailings s
JOIN (SELECT * from destinations LIMIT 2) d  
  ON s.destination = d.id
```

(You say you want to limit the `sailings` table, but I think you might want the limit on the `destinations` table, based on your expected output; you can adjust as necessary)

Comment: You rather need to limit  destination

Comment: @Ryan Unfortunately this does not work, still gives me the same results.

Comment: @CodeGodie - updated the restriction to destinations now - this works on the SQL fiddle

Comment: it still does not show me what I need (unless im not running the fiddle correctly). The results i get is 3 rather than 2 .. Can you post a link to the fiddle you created?